# Ffmpeg change aspect ratio do not succeeded

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to change the aspect ratio of video, cause it's being showed in a wrong way (it sould be 16:9 but shows 3:4).
I've tried a lot of things, and none worked.
E.g. I've tried to set SAR, but it changes DAR, so the aspect ratio stays the same. Here's an example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i rtmp://localhost/in/air-hdmi -vf "setsar=sar=16/9" -f flv rtmp://localhost/in/ngoraltestffmpeg 


    ffmpeg version N-80388-gfd1d84b Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/anastasia/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/anastasia/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/anastasia/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/anastasia/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 46.100 / 57. 46.100
  libavformat    57. 38.101 / 57. 38.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 46.101 /  6. 46.101
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100

[flv @ 0x38143c0] audio stream discovered after head already parsed
[aac @ 0x3818f20] element type mismatch 1 != 0
[flv @ 0x38143c0] video stream discovered after head already parsed
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://localhost/in/air-hdmi':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 720
    displayHeight   : 576
    fps             : 0
    profile         : 
    level           : 
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 181748.084000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x576, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
[flv @ 0x39bf5a0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://localhost/in/ngoraltest':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 720
    displayHeight   : 576
    fps             : 0
    profile         : 
    level           : 
    encoder         : Lavf57.38.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1 (flv) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:9 DAR 20:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.46.100 flv
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.46.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> flv1 (flv))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[aac @ 0x3a37000] element type mismatch 1 != 0
    Last message repeated 7 times
[flv @ 0x39bf5a0] Failed to update header with correct duration.ate= 942.7kbits/s speed=2.37x    
[flv @ 0x39bf5a0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame=  112 fps= 48 q=31.0 Lsize=     633kB time=00:00:05.18 bitrate= 999.9kbits/s speed=2.23x    
video:546kB audio:82kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.846813%
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

Using `setdar=16/9` do not succeeds: it changes PAR, so the result is the same:

```
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://localhost/in/air-hdmi':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 720
    displayHeight   : 576
    fps             : 0
    profile         : 
    level           : 
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 287464.746000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x576, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
[flv @ 0x3a5ea20] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://localhost/in/ngoraltest':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 720
    displayHeight   : 576
    fps             : 0
    profile         : 
    level           : 
    encoder         : Lavf57.38.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1 (flv) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.46.100 flv
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.46.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> flv1 (flv))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

(When use `setsar`, the params are `720x576 [SAR 16:9 DAR 20:9]`, when `setdar` -- `720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9]`)

I've also tried to apply `scale=720:-1` and `-aspect 16:9` and all left the same.

*BUT*! Wnen I write `ffplay -vf setsar=16/9 rtmp://localhost/in/ngoraltest` it shows perfectly what I need.
What could be thae problem and hoe to solve it?

P.S. I'm little bit confused that there's no onformation about SAR and DAR of input signal, but I can do totally nothing with it.

Comment: You're using the encoder `flv1`. I doubt you want that.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Whatshoul I use? And HOW? :)

Comment: Add `-c:v libx264` as an output option for H.264 video.

Answer (score 6):

```
ffmpeg -i infile -aspect 16:9 -c copy outputfile
```

From the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options):

> Set the video display aspect ratio. If `-aspect` is used together when
>   [stream copying](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy), it will affect the aspect ratio stored at
>   container level, but not the aspect ratio stored in encoded frames, if
>   it exists.

From what I know.  There is this problem with video media when the DAR numbers get high.  I guess the media is so tightly wound up and it will not concat to other media with the same aspect.  The only way I can see around this is converting it to raw format and recompressing it.  I encountered this problem when I tried to concat or splice video clips together.  Numbers that do not match up the DAR in different files give an error.  I was forced to use windows movie maker to attach the media manually.

Comment: If you read my question, you could notice I've tried it. Also `-c:v copy ` throws an error if used with `-aspect` cause aspect obviously changes codec

Comment: @Ngoral `-aspect` does work with `-c:v copy` for some container formats, but I'm not familiar enough with FLV and RTMP to know offhand if it will work and I didn't investigate or test. However, you did not provide the actual error, and you omitted the `ffmpeg` configure and version info which is important to include. How are we to know if you are not using an ancient `ffmpeg`?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Yes, sorry, everything has mixed in my mind, it works with `c:v copy`. Anyway, that does not help. I also updated logs, so that you can see version and all dependencies

Comment: This answer is fantastic. It does not re-encode anything, it just changes the metadata for SAR/DAR, so it finishes in a few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
ffmpeg -y -i rtmp://localhost/in/air-hdmi -vf "setdar=16/9" -f flv rtmp://localhost/in/ngoraltestffmpeg
```

`setsar` is the aspect ratio of a sample i.e. one pixel. `setdar` is for the video. Of course, what `setdar` does is change the SAR, taking into account the dimensions of the video, so that the display ratio is obtained. `DAR = Width x SAR / height`

Comment: I thought I actually need to sat to encoder/decoder that my pixels should be some other form. Anyway, that does not work :(

Comment: According to the console output you pasted, the DAR of the output is 16:9, so the values are correct. Is your video already letterboxed? Paste a screenshot from the original video. You can also skip the ratio flags by scaling directly. `ffmpeg -y -i rtmp://... -vf "scale=1024:576,setsar=1" -f flv rtmp://...`

Answer (score 1):

So, based on everything here, I had the same issue and tried something super simple that worked: (in my case, it was displaying as 4:3 but I needed it to display as 16:9)

Note, however,  that I was informed by the output of my first failed try, it told me this:

```
Stream #0:0: Video ...(other stuff)... 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], ... (other stuff)...
```

So I figured I just needed to change DAR 4:3, and so I just ran this:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.avi" -vf setdar=16:9 -c:a copy "output.mp4"
```

and it worked like a charm.

Comment: 1. This will re-encode the video. 2. This didn't work for me. It changed my video from `1440x1080, SAR 1:1, DAR 4:3` to `1440x1080, SAR 27:4, DAR 9:1`, which was totally wrong. I would recommend others to first try [the answer `-aspect 16:9 -c copy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40706888/ffmpeg-change-aspect-ratio-do-not-succeeded/40711394#40711394), which is lossless and fast.